# ERROR: The option setting 'android.experimental.testOptions.emulatorSnapshots.maxSnapshotsForTestFailures=0' is experimental

Tags: java, android-studio, build.gradle, emulador

Me sale este error al iniciar el emulador. He comprobado las propiedades del build.gradle y no aparece que tenga eso activado. He buscado tambien en Edit>Find>Find in Files para buscarlo en todo el proyecto y nada.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar lo que hay en tu archivo `gradle.properties`? ¿Has probado a borrar el emulador totalmente?

Comment: Agrega más información a tu pregunta, por ejemplo el contenido del archivo gradle.properties

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: @YagoRodriguez, agrega tu build.gradle y busca "moduleData.id"